# search and replace DOM elements in Java

Tags: java, dom, tree, replace

I'm looking for a way to write a search and replace method using W3C DOM to update a tree.  I've thought about doing a breadth-first search as below, but can't think of how to do the in place replacement?

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

private Element tree;

public void searchReplace(Node x, Node y){
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(tree);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = q.remove();
        if (current == x){
            // do replacement
        }

        NodeList children = current.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            q.add(children.item(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only interested in replacing the node name not its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rename a node, there is no need a for a `searchReplace()` method (since you already have the Node in question), just call `renameNode()` on the `Document` in question. eg.

```
document.renameNode(node, null, "new name");
```

Comment: this is especially important for Java 6, while using an empty string instead of null will work in Java 8, Java 6 will throw a org.w3c.dom.DOMException with HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR within the message

Answer (score 1):

To replace an `Element`, you can use `Node#replaceChild()`. E.g., to replace `current` by `y` you would use

```
current.getParentNode().replaceChild(y, current)
```

Comment: I get an exception doing that HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.

Comment: From the JavaDoc: "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: Raised if this node is of a type that does not allow children of the type of the newChild node, or if the node to put in is one of this node's ancestors or this node itself."

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XPath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) class for searching the DOM. For usage understanding see this [simple example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html#N100C7).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its possible with a wrapper api, such as JDom, but even then I'm not sure if that will preserve child element orders (doublefull).  You are potentially looking at rolling your own implementation of DOM interfaces.